# Include ID from MySQL to each item in ListView and pass to second activity

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I hava a `ListView` which is populated from MySQL. Now I'm trying when I click on item of this listview to open another activity and grab some more info for that item(ID). I've tried with intent. In `FirstAActivity.java`

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("id", position);
       intent.putExtra("text", text);                
       startActivity(intent);
}
```

And `SecondActivity.java`

```
String text;
int id;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        id = (Integer) intent.getExtras().get("id");
        text = (String) intent.getExtras().get("text");
        textView.setText(id+"");
    }

}
```

And the `second_activity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/restaurants_buttons"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="" 
</LinearLayout>
```

When I open `SecondActivity` is empty. Apparently this put and get extras are wrong. Also I don't understand how this can be done at all. I mean in my table I have `id`, `name`, `text`. In listview I show only `name`. In SecondActivity (when I clicked on name ) want to load `name` and `text`.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675806/passing-intent-cant-get-extra/26675994#26675994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to forget to set the id in the textview :

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);        
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
id = (Integer) intent.getExtras().get("id");
textview.setText(id+"");
```

If the above code still not working, try to change it like this :

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);        
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null) {
id = b.getInt("id");
textview.setText(id+"");
```

Comment: I got id 0 on first item whit both examples?

Comment: intent.putExtra("id", position); Have you make sure the position is 1?

Comment: No? How can I check about position?

Comment: This from `logcat` when load first activity. `11-06 08:46:53.940: E/err(845): 1 rest1.jpg` I believe this `1` before image is the ID that I get from MySQL. Other results are similar whit 2...3...4..n.

Comment: Ah .. I think I understand now. Here I don't care what is this 0.. this is the position of listview. I care for the `id` that stay behind this `0`, right? And in this case `0` will load content for `id=1` from DB?

Comment: Yes, you should pass the id of clicked item, not the position in your case.

Comment: I've edited my question added in `FirstAtivity`, `SecondActivity`, `second_activity.xml` `text` which I also got from DB. Now when I run secondactivity got blank page again. Any idea?

Comment: @Goro try to use my second code and see if theres any difference. I never used your code, so not sure if it will be working..

Comment: Both examples load empty activity

Comment: Put a logcat inside if (intent.getExtras() != null) to see whether the intent null or not

Comment: I've put in this `IF` -> `Log.e("If is null", "is null");` and I get `11-06 09:10:09.237: E/If is null(1577): is null
` in logcat

Comment: Is this mean that the problem is in my FirstActivity?

Comment: When I remove `text` is not null any more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64409/discussion-between-blaze-tama-and-goro).

Answer (score 2):

```
use this On SecondActivity.java


int id;
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);  
id= getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
textview.setText(id+"");
```

Comment: Here also when I click on first item I get ID=0 .. which I think is wrong. It must be 1 because in DB is 1.

Comment: no this is Right it is the position of list view have u check it on (int position) OnItemclickListner and also u k now List view position Like 0,1,2,3,----

Answer (score 2):

There is two way pass/get data one activity to another activity.

1.add data to intent.

how to put :

```
intent.putExtra("id", position);
```

how to get :

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

2.Add data to bundle and add bundle to intent.

how to put :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("id", position);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

how to get :

```
String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
```