# How to change EditText to int and display it in new page

Tags: android, eclipse, string, int

i am facing this problem right now. please help me...

i have this editText textbox. below is the code.

```
      <EditText
    android:id="@+id/nog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"/>
```

i want user to only input numbers, so i already declare the inputType. 
after user enter the number in the EditText, they will click a proceed button that will display the number that they enter just now ( which means it will be displayed in new page).

the problems is that, i cannot retrieve the value from the EditText textbox.

this is the code of the page that will display the number that they enter before.

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView25"
    android:text="Number of guest(s) : " />
```

the problem is i don't know how to get the value in the EditText box.

```
 intent.putExtra("", .isChecked());
```

the code intent is not working as i understand....please help me

UPDATE LATEST

doReceipt.java

```
     package com.example.mobilecatering;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class doReceipt extends Activity

 {
boolean nsPutih, nsBeriyani,nsMinyak,aymKurma,aymLemak,aymKari,aymRendang,aymMerah,
prtAsam, dggTomato, dggSinggang, dggMerah,kerabuTaugeh, pindangKacang,jelatah,dalcaSayur,papadom,
kariIkan,ikanMasin, sirapAis, oren,tehTarik,agarAgar, buburKacang,kuih, price;



TextView tvOutput1,tvOutput2, tvOutput3, tvOutput4, tvOutput5, tvOutput6, tvOutput7, tvOutput8, tvOutput9, tvOutput10, 
tvOutput11, tvOutput12, tvOutput13, tvOutput14, tvOutput15, tvOutput16, tvOutput17, tvOutput18, tvOutput19, tvOutput20,
tvOutput21, tvOutput22, tvOutput23, tvOutput24, tvOutput25, tvOutput26, tvOutput27, tvOutput28;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.receipt);

        if(getIntent().getIntExtra("nog",0)!=0)
        tvOutput27.setText("Number of guest(s) : "+ getIntent().getIntExtra("nog",0));



      tvOutput1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      tvOutput2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      tvOutput3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
      tvOutput4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
      tvOutput5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
      tvOutput6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
      tvOutput7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
      tvOutput8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
      tvOutput9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
      tvOutput10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
      tvOutput11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
      tvOutput12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
      tvOutput13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
      tvOutput14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
      tvOutput15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
      tvOutput16 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
      tvOutput17 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView17);
      tvOutput18 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView18);
      tvOutput19 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView19);
      tvOutput20 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView20);
      tvOutput21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
      tvOutput22 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
      tvOutput23 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView23);
      tvOutput24 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView24);
      tvOutput25 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView25);
      tvOutput26 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView26);
      tvOutput27 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView27);


      Bundle data = this.getIntent().getExtras();

      nsPutih=data.getBoolean("nsPutih");
      nsBeriyani=data.getBoolean("nsBeriyani");
      nsMinyak=data.getBoolean("nsMinyak");
      aymKurma=data.getBoolean("aymKurma");
      aymLemak=data.getBoolean("aymLemak");
      aymKari=data.getBoolean("aymKari");
      aymRendang=data.getBoolean("aymRendang");
      aymMerah=data.getBoolean("aymMerah");
      prtAsam=data.getBoolean("prtAsam");
      dggTomato=data.getBoolean("dggTomato");
      dggSinggang=data.getBoolean("dggSinggang");
      dggMerah=data.getBoolean("dggMerah");
      kerabuTaugeh=data.getBoolean("kerabuTaugeh");
      pindangKacang=data.getBoolean("pindangKacang");
      jelatah=data.getBoolean("jelatah");
      dalcaSayur=data.getBoolean("dalcaSayur");
      papadom=data.getBoolean("papadom");
      kariIkan=data.getBoolean("kariIkan");
      ikanMasin=data.getBoolean("ikanMasin");
      sirapAis=data.getBoolean("sirapAis");
      oren=data.getBoolean("oren");
      tehTarik=data.getBoolean("tehTarik");
      agarAgar=data.getBoolean("agarAgar");
      buburKacang=data.getBoolean("buburKacang");
      kuih=data.getBoolean("kuih");
      price=data.getBoolean("price");


      double price = 0;


      if(nsPutih==true)
      {

          tvOutput1.setText("Nasi Putih - RM 1.00");
          tvOutput1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=1;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (nsBeriyani==true)
      {
          tvOutput2.setText("Nasi Beriyani - RM 2.00");
          tvOutput2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=2.0;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
      if (nsMinyak==true)
      {
          tvOutput3.setText("Nasi Minyak - RM 1.50");
          tvOutput3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=1.5;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
      if(aymKurma==true)
      {
          tvOutput4.setText("Ayam Masak Kurma - RM 2.00");
          tvOutput4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=2;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
      if (aymLemak==true)
      {
          tvOutput5.setText("Ayam Masak Lemak - RM 4.00");
          tvOutput5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=4;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (aymKari==true)
      {
          tvOutput6.setText("Ayam Masak Kari - RM 4.00");
          tvOutput6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=4;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (aymRendang==true)
      {
          tvOutput7.setText("Ayam Masak Rendang - RM 4.00");
          tvOutput7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=4;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (aymMerah==true)
      {
          tvOutput8.setText("Ayam Masak Merah - RM 4.00");
          tvOutput8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=4;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (prtAsam==true)
      {
          tvOutput9.setText("Perut Air Asam - RM 3.00");
          tvOutput9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=3;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (dggTomato==true)
      {
          tvOutput10.setText("Daging Masak Tomato - RM 4.00");
          tvOutput10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=4;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (dggSinggang==true)
      {
          tvOutput11.setText("Daging Masak Singgang - RM 4.00");
          tvOutput11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=4;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (dggMerah==true)
      {
          tvOutput12.setText("Daging Masak Merah - RM 4.00");
          tvOutput12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=4;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput12.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (kerabuTaugeh==true)
      {
          tvOutput13.setText("Kerabu Taugeh - RM 1.50");
          tvOutput13.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=1.5;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput13.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (pindangKacang==true)
      {
          tvOutput14.setText("Pindang Kacang - RM 1.00");
          tvOutput14.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=1;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput14.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (jelatah==true)
      {
          tvOutput15.setText("Jelatah - RM 2.00");
          tvOutput15.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=2;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput15.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (dalcaSayur==true)
      {
          tvOutput16.setText("Dalca Sayur - RM 1.50");
          tvOutput16.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=1.5;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput16.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (papadom==true)
      {
          tvOutput17.setText("Papadom - RM 0.50");
          tvOutput17.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=0.5;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput17.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (kariIkan==true)
      {
          tvOutput18.setText("Kari Ikan - RM 1.50");
          tvOutput18.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=1.5;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput18.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (ikanMasin==true)
      {
          tvOutput19.setText("Kari Ikan Masin - RM 4.00");
          tvOutput19.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=4;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput19.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (sirapAis==true)
      {
          tvOutput20.setText("Sirap Ais - RM 1.00");
          tvOutput20.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=1;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput20.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (oren==true)
      {
          tvOutput21.setText("Oren - RM 1.00");
          tvOutput21.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=1;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput21.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (tehTarik==true)
      {
          tvOutput22.setText("Teh Tarik - RM 1.20");
          tvOutput22.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=1.2;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput22.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (agarAgar==true)
      {
          tvOutput23.setText("Agar Agar - RM 1.00");
          tvOutput23.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=1;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput23.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (buburKacang==true)
      {
          tvOutput24.setText("Bubur Kacang - RM 2.50");
          tvOutput24.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=2.5;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput24.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if (kuih==true)
      {
          tvOutput25.setText("Kuih Muih - RM 1.00");
          tvOutput25.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          price+=1;
      }
      else
      {
          tvOutput25.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      Log.e("MENU PAKEJ A","Total Price: RM "+ price);
         String stringdouble= Double.toString(price);
         tvOutput26.setText("\n\n Total Price : RM "+ stringdouble);

            }
public void goHome(View v)
{
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,0);
 }
    }

}
```

this is the mcpakej1.java

package com.example.mobilecatering;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox; 
import android.widget.EditText;

public class mcpakej1 extends Activity 
{
 EditText editText;
CheckBox nsPutih,nsBeriyani,nsMinyak,aymKurma,aymLemak,aymKari,aymRendang,aymMerah,
prtAsam, dggTomato, dggSinggang, dggMerah,kerabuTaugeh, pindangKacang,jelatah,dalcaSayur,papadom,
kariIkan,ikanMasin, sirapAis, oren,tehTarik,agarAgar, buburKacang,kuih;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.mcpakej1);


  nsPutih       = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA1);
  nsBeriyani    = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA2);
  nsMinyak      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA3);
  aymKurma      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA4);
  aymLemak      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA5);
  aymKari       = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA6);
  aymRendang    = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA7);
  aymMerah      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA8);
  prtAsam       = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA9);
  dggTomato     = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA10);
  dggSinggang   = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA11);
  dggMerah      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA12);
  kerabuTaugeh  = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA13);
  pindangKacang = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA14);
  jelatah       = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA15);
  dalcaSayur    = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA16);
  papadom       = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA17);
  kariIkan      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA18);
  ikanMasin     = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA19);
  sirapAis      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA20);
  oren          = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA21);
  tehTarik      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA22);
  agarAgar      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA23);
  buburKacang   = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA24);
  kuih          = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA25);


}

public void goHome(View v){
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);}
}

public void goReceipt(View v) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), doReceipt.class);

    intent.putExtra("nsBeriyani", nsBeriyani.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("nsPutih", nsPutih.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("nsMinyak", nsMinyak.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("aymKurma", aymKurma.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("aymKari", aymKari.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("aymRendang", aymRendang.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("aymMerah", aymMerah.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("prtAsam", prtAsam.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("dggTomato", dggTomato.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("dggSinggang", dggSinggang.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("dggMerah", dggMerah.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("kerabuTaugeh", kerabuTaugeh.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("pindangKacang", pindangKacang.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("jelatah", jelatah.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("dalcaSayur", dalcaSayur.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("papadom", papadom.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("kariIkan", kariIkan.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("ikanMasin", ikanMasin.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("sirapAis", sirapAis.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("oren", oren.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("tehTarik", tehTarik.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("agarAgar", agarAgar.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("buburKacang", buburKacang.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("kuih", kuih.isChecked());


    Intent nextPage= new Intent(this, doReceipt.class);
    nextPage.putExtra("nog",Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString()));


    startActivityForResult(intent,0);



    }  
 }
```

this is the logcat error.

```
  11-07 09:21:14.179: E/AndroidRuntime(281):    at com.example.mobilecatering.mcpakej1.goReceipt(mcpakej1.java:90)
```

Comment: pass the value in `Bundle`

Comment: this is the error i get.The method getText() is undefined for the type Bundle

Comment: can you post doReceipt activity code ?

Comment: i have update my doReceipt code.i don't know what value should be replace with someDefaultValue....help me plz... :(

Comment: where you stuck now ?

Comment: write it as : `if(getIntent().getIntExtra("nog",0)!=0)`

Comment: @CikHusna,please check my updated ans.

Comment: @SweetWisherツ i had remove ; from if statement, and replace someDefaultValue with 0...when i run the prog, the prog stop unexpectedly. i check logcat and i get this error.  at com.example.mobilecatering.mcpakej1.goReceipt(mcpakej1.java:88). i'll update the code for mcpakej1.java

Comment: what is at line 90 in mcpakej1.java??? @CikHusna

Comment: replace `startActivityForResult(intent,0);` with `startActivity(nextPage);`

Comment: the prog cannot run. it still stop unexpectedly.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Pass the value like :

```
Intent nextPage= new Intent(this, NextPage.class);
nextPage.putExtra("myValue",Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString()));
startActivity(nextPage);
```

Fetch value as :

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null)
    {
        Integer value= bundle.getInt("myValue");
    }
```

## Update:

The error you getting nog cannot be resolved just because you haven't assigned the EditText you want to use. Use this code :

Take a reference of EditText in OnCreate :

```
 EditText yourEditText;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.mcpakej1);

      yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nog);
    }
```

## Update :2

doReceipt.java :

```
public class doReceipt extends Activity

{


     TextView tvOutput27;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.receipt);


        tvOutput27 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView27);

        if(getIntent().getIntExtra("nog",0)!=0){
              tvOutput27.setText("Number of guest(s) : "+ getIntent().getIntExtra("nog",0));
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: you directly put data in intent and get using bundle so if you pass value directly to intent you get directly from intent and if you pass value using bundle then you get value using bundle.

Comment: have you ever tried this code ?? It works perfect. The data which we pass in Intent are bundled and passed to next activity. so you can get it in `getExtra` only (ie in a BUNDLE only)

Comment: is it should be like this?


public class mcpakej1 extends Activity 
{public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.mcpakej1);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nog);
 }
  public void goReceipt(View v) 
 {
  Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), doReceipt.class);

Intent nextPage= new Intent(this, doReceipt.class);
  nextPage.putExtra("nog",Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString()));
  
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
        
   }
}

Comment: thankz....my 1st activity have no error anymore. for fetching, i had try your code..  yourTextView.setText("Number of guest(s) : "+ getIntent().getIntExtra("myValue",someDefaultValue)).. but for someDefaultValue, i don't understand. what should i put?

Comment: i put the code in the onCreate like this...

  if(getIntent().getIntExtra("nog",0)!=null)

it give me error... :(

Comment: i cannot run the prog. i don't know what value should i replace at someDefaultValue

Comment: replace it with 0 and check it with 0 only

Comment: sorry..but the prog still close unexpectedly. and the error in the logcat is still showing error in mcpakej1.java

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `isChecked()`? It should be :

```
intent.putExtra("nog", nog.getText().toString());
```

In your 2nd activity :

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null) {
String nog = b.getString("nog");
//use the nog
```

Comment: Check my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675806/passing-intent-cant-get-extra/26675994#26675994

Comment: @HareshChhelana Sorry, my answer is not wrong. Your answer only the other way to do it. Just test my code if you dont believe :) Thanks anyway

Comment: sorry. which one should i follow in your ans. @Haresh Chhelana add data to intent or add data to bundle?

Comment: @CikHusna both of our code is working, its up to you :)

Comment: @CikHusna you dont need to declare the bundle in the 1st activity. You just need to send the data via intent.putExtra, and create a bundle to "catch" that data in the 2nd activity :)

Comment: if i just write 
  intent.putExtra("nog", nog.getText().toString());

in my first activity and not declare nog to int or bundle etc, it will display error like nog cannot be resolved

Comment: it means you havn't declared `nog as an EditText`

Comment: add `EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nog);` in OnCreate.. Check my Answer

Answer (score 0):

```
   mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
   mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nog);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Log.v("EditText", mEdit.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Get value from EditTex and pass to inetnt :

```
intent.putExtra("value", nog.getText().toString());
```

Get value from intent and set to TextView :

```
textView27.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("value"));
```

**Hows your actual code are working :**

```
public class a extends Activity {

    private EditText nogEditText;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mcpakej1);

        nogEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nog);

    }

    public void goReceipt(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, doReceipt.class);
        intent.putExtra("nog", nogEditText.getText().toString());
        startActivityForResult(intent,0);
    }
}

public class doReceipt extends Activity {

    private TextView textView27;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.receipt);

        textView27 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView27);

        textView27.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("nog"));

    }

}
```

Comment: the code intent is displaying an error.Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type int

Comment: have u check android:inputType="number"

Comment: i have update the code that i use to declare the nog

Comment: i had run the prog and it close unexpectedly. the logcat error state that there is error in mcpakej1.java.

Comment: please check updated ans it was mistake please try to replace this line :  Intent intent = new Intent(this, doReceipt.class);